# Go back button acts as Go up in Dolphin

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, search, dolphin, button

When I search for a file or folder in Dolphin then click a file or folder and want to go back, clicking the `<` button, it does not go back to the search results.
[image] 
It goes up ( like this `^` button would do). Is this problem (I think it is a problem, because every time I need to do the search again) normal behaviour? When not searching it works correctly, doing what it should do: go back to the previous location. And the up button does what it should do: go 1 layer up. Does anybody know how to change this behaviour? 
I use:
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-40-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB
with Mint 20.3 Una and Windows 10 in triple boot on a HP Envy ce1000n.

Comment: That is probably a current limitation in the implementation of the back button, worthy filing as an issue if that has not yet been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the 'back'button 3 times. That will get you back to the search results.

Comment: That works. Thank you so much.